# Copy row plus next 3

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have the below code that works great. It parses through all my sheets and finds the row in column A that I want and pastes it to a specified worksheet. However, I need it to copy the specified row plus the next X number of rows. Can someone help me accomplish this?

```
Sub FindValues()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        i = 1

        Do While i <= LastRow
            If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "OwnershipType Ownership Type" Then
                ws.Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
                i = i - 1
                LastRow = LastRow - 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Play with `ws.Rows(i).Copy` - change that to like `ws.Rows(i & ":" & i+3).Copy`. BTW: remove `i = i -1` and `lastrow = lastrow - 1` those 2 make no sense. Just leave the last `i = i + 1` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can amend the range of rows being copied on this line like so:

```
ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + 3).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
```

If the match was found in row 1 for example, the code would render as `ws.Rows(1:4).Copy`

Comment: Perfect! I figured it was easy enough but I couldn't get it to work. I kept trying to set a range. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some minor modifications. Just added **(i + number of rows to be copied)**. Check the below code:
Used Integer *copyrw* in the code, you can set this integer to copy the number of rows.

```
Sub FindValues()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim copyrw as Integer

copyrw = 3
For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1

    Do While i <= LastRow
        If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "OwnershipType Ownership Type" Then
            ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + copyrw).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
            i = i - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: what's the point of `i = i - 1` and `lastRow = lastRow - 1` and then increasing the `i` past the `End If`?

Comment: Hmmmm... That's bit strange peice of coding.